# Select only string with number SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string

I need select only strings in my table, but this table has numbers and strings together.

Ex:

```
ID Name
1  Jacke11
2  Andre
3  Rodrigo11
4  55555
```

My select need return only Ids: 1, 2, 3.

Thanks

Comment: Eh, is id really a separate column and name a separate column?

Comment: if your select needs to return only 1, 2, 3, you need only integers from the table. Is separated by spaces?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
SELECT ID
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(Name + '.0e0') = 0
```

Comment: I think I know why, but you can comment on why you're doing `+ '.0e0'` as I don't think it's very intuitive to need that.

Comment: @Yuck - Because you can get unexpected matches with `ISNUMERIC` since it will evaluate `TRUE` for non-int datatypes like float (also money and some symbols).  `12e10` will pass `ISNUMERIC` as `TRUE`.  By adding the `.0e0` you force it to check only for integer values.

Comment: @Yuck: Without that ISNUMERIC will return a 1 for such things as '+' and '$'.

Comment: Using ISNUMERIC for this will cause a lot more trouble. The most correct and performative answer at the moment is @JNK [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8840291/2738309).

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to Joe's very fine `ISNUMERIC` solution, you can use `PATINDEX` to make sure you have an alpha character:

```
SELECT ID
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', name) > 0
```

This may be slightly faster since it will stop searching the string as soon as it gets to the first alpha character.

Comment: to avoid an exception I would put a COALESCE(name, '') or something similar