# SQL select aggregate group by: exclude certain value based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like the following:

```
trans_id  index_no    meals     tips   coverage  SID
021253    DET98313    30.50     2.54   CORP      ZX984784
031823    DET98313    20.45     0.89   SELF      ZX984784
017265    DET98313    22.48     2.89   CORP      ZX984784
051346    DET98313    18.63     2.02   SELF      ZX984784
 EX023    DET98313    23.45     1.45   CORP      LN874742
...
```

Where the shown rows form a group identified by `index_no` and subgroups identified by `coverage`.

What I want to do is calculate a sum for both `meals` and `tips` in the group and also get the `SID` which is `ZX984784`.

What I can do to exclude `UN874742` is that I know the trans_ID will start with two letters instead of just numbers like the other rows.

Right now I came up with the following query:

```
SELECT index_no, 
    coverage,
    SUM(meals) as meals,
    SUM(tips) as tips,
    MIN(SID) as SID
FROM
    myTable
GROUP BY
    index_no, coverage
```

But MIN(SID) cannot guarantee to give me the SID `ZX984784`.

My desired output is this:

```
index_no    coverage  meals     tips      SID
DET98313        CORP  76.43     6.88   ZX984784
DET98313        SELF  39.08     2.91   ZX984784
```

`
How can I include the last row in the SUM operation but at the same time exclude it when retrieving SID?

Comment: What database is this? SQL Server??

Comment: Please include your rdbms tag.

Comment: Can you not just add a group by for SID?  Will the SID be different for records that are in the same index_no and coverage groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following idea should work in most databases:

```
select . . .,
       min(case when substring(trans_id, 1, 1) between 'A' and 'Z' and
                     substring(trans_id, 2, 1) between 'A' and 'Z'
                 then NULL else SID
           end)
```

And this is probably good enough:

```
select . . .,
       min(case when substring(trans_id, 1, 2) between 'AA' and 'ZZ' 
                 then NULL else SID
           end)
```

Note: some databases call `substring()`, `substr()`.

Most databases have some special purpose mechanism that is easier.  For instance, in SQL Server:

```
select . . .,
       min(case when trans_id like '[A-Z][A-Z]%'
                 then NULL else SID
           end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably can make a conditional `MIN`

This use `isnumeric` from SQL SERVER

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ba010/1)

```
SELECT index_no, 
    coverage,
    SUM(meals) as meals,
    SUM(tips) as tips,
    MIN( CASE 
           WHEN ISNUMERIC(trans_id  + '.0e0') = 1 THEN SID
           ELSE NULL
         END ) as SID
FROM
    myTable
GROUP BY
    index_no, coverage
```

[Select only string with number SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840142/select-only-string-with-number-sql-server)